# The multifier identifier could not be bound in update statement

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to execute this query on sql server 2008r2-

```
SELECT @lUpd1 = 'UPDATE ts1cust.dbo.t_grgr_xwalk 
SET    xwalk.WEB = info.WEB,xwalk.AVIVIA = info.AVIVIA,xwalk.MSP = info.MSP,xwalk.QO   =    info.QO
FROM   ts1cust.dbo.t_plan_mspqo_info info, ts1cust.dbo.t_grgr_xwalk xwalk
WHERE  info.PLANID = xwalk.ID_471'
```

but getting below mentioned error-

```
 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "xwalk.WEB" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allowed to use multi-part identifiers for the assignment side of columns in the `SET` clause.

```
SELECT @lUpd1 = 'UPDATE xwalk
SET    WEB = info.WEB, --<-- no xwalk. here
       AVIVIA = info.AVIVIA,
       MSP = info.MSP,
       QO   =    info.QO
FROM   ts1cust.dbo.t_plan_mspqo_info info
   INNER JOIN
       ts1cust.dbo.t_grgr_xwalk xwalk
         ON  info.PLANID = xwalk.ID_471'
```

I've also taken the liberty of replacing the table reference with the alias you're using at the top of the `UPDATE`, and switched to using ANSI `JOIN` rather than `,`

Answer (score 0):

You alias your table `t_grgr_xwalk` as `xwalk`, so for the first expression `Update Table` You should use `xwalk` too.

```
SELECT @lUpd1 = 'UPDATE xwalk
SET    WEB = info.WEB,
       AVIVIA = info.AVIVIA,
       MSP = info.MSP,
       QO = info.QO
FROM   ts1cust.dbo.t_plan_mspqo_info info, ts1cust.dbo.t_grgr_xwalk xwalk
WHERE  info.PLANID = xwalk.ID_471'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below:
SELECT @lUpd1 = 'UPDATE ts1cust.dbo.t_grgr_xwalk xwalk
SET    xwalk.WEB = info.WEB,xwalk.AVIVIA = info.AVIVIA,xwalk.MSP = info.MSP,xwalk.QO   =    info.QO
FROM   ts1cust.dbo.t_plan_mspqo_info info
WHERE  info.PLANID = xwalk.ID_471'